# url value not changing through loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display the comments by the user from the database and +1 could be given to their comment. this is the view.

```
  <br>Comments:<br>
    @foreach($show as $sh)
    <span class="comment">{{$sh->comment}} --<b style="color:blue">{{$sh->name}},</b> {{$sh->email}}</span>
    <form method="POST" action="{{url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}")}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}<input type="submit" value="+1"> 
    Total score: <mark>{{$sh->score}}</mark><br><br>
    @endforeach
```

but i am redirected to `/review/now/add/1` with every +1 button i click. I am supposed to +1 the comment i click and store it's score in database. `comment`, `name`,adn `score` are the database columns.

Route:

```
Route::post('/review/now/add/{id}','reviewcontroller@nowadd');
```

Controller:

```
public function nowadd($id)
  {
        $add=review::where('id',$id)->get();
        $count=$add->score;
        $now=$count+1;
        $nowadd= review::where('id',$id)->update(['score'=>$now]);  
        return redirect('/review')
        ->with('message','your have +1 d the comment.' );      
}
```

with that where clause i am supposed to select the row of that id in the url and add +1 to the score of that id. but i am failing here too. it displays undefined property score. the $add might be an array which is causing this error. but how could it be? i am selecting only one row with that id. And when i use `first();` instead of `get();` everything is fine but only for 1st comment.

Comment: i use first(); instead of get(); everything is fine but only for 1st comment.@AchrafKhouadja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function nowadd($id)
{
        review::where('id', $id)->increment('score',1);  // assuming that score is a column in your review database
        return redirect('/review')
        ->with('message','your have +1 d the comment.' );      
}
```

**UPDATE :**  close the form

```
 <br>Comments:<br>
    @foreach($show as $sh)
    <span class="comment">{{$sh->comment}} --<b style="color:blue">{{$sh->name}},</b> {{$sh->email}}</span>
       <form method="POST" action="{{url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}")}}">
         {!! csrf_field() !!}<input type="submit" value="+1">
       </form> 
    Total score: <mark>{{$sh->score}}</mark><br><br>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I am not redirected to id other than one. url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}") here.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: If i submit the respective form url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}") is always /review/now/add/1.  Not 2,3 etc.

Comment: maybe because you didnt didnt add the close form tag ? after the input field add </form> and try

Comment: btw , use my controller code, it looks cleaner i think, ^^

Answer (score 1):

`get()` method will return [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) class, and `first()` will return [Model](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) class which is the first model instance in the query

In order to update, you need to use model not collection. When you are trying to access `score` attributes on Collection, it won't work since `score` attribute is on model not collection

You can actually use collection, and query using foreach which will give you a model at each iteration

Comment: I am not redirected to id other than one. url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}") here.

Comment: @Steve: Where do you want to redirect?

Comment: If i submit the respective form url("/review/now/add/{$sh->id}") is always /review/now/add/1.  Not 2,3 etc.

Comment: @Steve Can you inspect element to see the url of the form is actually correct and not always 1? Need to make sure it is view issues or backend

Comment: @Steve That is what I thought. Something on frontend.  Because everything looks fine on backend. Great everything works!

Comment: I think i was the fast guy :p glad things worked for you